# Displaying image and pass dynamic data to pyrocms page

Tags: image, codeigniter, dynamic-data, pyrocms

i need to display an image on a page which i developed from content/pages. But i dont know how i can display image and pass dynamic data to this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! after waiting for people to answer i did some research and found that this work is done through tags and involves the use of partials.

Comment: Partials are optional, you don't NEED to use them. Tags can be used to insert images, or you can use HTML. You can do whatever you like... More information would have gotten you an answer.